# Understanding proportion of variance in PCA

Tags: self-study, variance, pca

One of my exam question was as follows:

> Assume the covariance matrix of your dataset $X $ is $\Sigma$ and while doing Principal Component Analysis, you found  $\Sigma =  CDC^T $. Here $D $ is the following diagonal matrix:
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 2.1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1.4 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & .9 \\\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Then the proportion of variance (POV) is explained by the first 2 principal components would be (accurate until 2 decimal places):
>
> - A) .85
> - B) .68
> - C) .31
> - D) 1
> - E) None of the above answer are correct

I know for a fact that E) is the correct answer. However, in my calculations i seem to get B) as the correct answer, calculating it as $(3 + 2.1) / (3 + 2.1 + 1.4 + 0.9) = 0.689... $

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proportion of explained variance by the first $k$ components in PCA is equal to $$R^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i}{\sum\lambda_i},$$ which in your case gives $0.689...$ as you correctly computed. However, when rounded up to two decimal places (as explicitly specified in the question), it becomes $0.69$ and not $0.68$. This is **perhaps** why (E), and not (B), is supposed to be the correct answer.

I must add that if so, this is a truly moronic exam question.